# Implicit cast array

Tags: c#

I have two classes that are atm that same and defined cast:

```
 public static implicit operator SponsoredBrandViewModel(SponsoredBrand sponsoredBrand)
        =>
            new SponsoredBrandViewModel
            {
                Id = sponsoredBrand.Id,
                BrandId = sponsoredBrand.RelatedEntityId,
                To = sponsoredBrand.To,
                From = sponsoredBrand.From,
                Importance = sponsoredBrand.Importance
            };
    public static implicit operator SponsoredBrand(SponsoredBrandViewModel sponsoredBrandViewModel)
        =>
            new SponsoredBrand
            {
                Id = sponsoredBrandViewModel.Id,
                RelatedEntityId = sponsoredBrandViewModel.BrandId,
                To = sponsoredBrandViewModel.To,
                From = sponsoredBrandViewModel.From,
                Importance = sponsoredBrandViewModel.Importance
            };
```

I want to make it cast when it's a array.

```
ar dbSponsoredBrands = await this._sponsoredBrandRepository.GetAsync();
            var viewModels = (IEnumerable<SponsoredBrandViewModel>) dbSponsoredBrands.ToEnumerable();
```

But this throwing invalidcast exception.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to cast the collection object `IEnumerable<SponsoredBrand>` into an `IEnumerable<SponsoredBrandViewModel>` where you've defined your implicit cast operator for the actual object. You'll need to iterate through the collection and create a new one, e.g.

```
var dbSponsoredBrands = await this._sponsoredBrandRepository.GetAsync();
var viewModels = dbSponsoredBrands.Select(x => (SponsoredBrandViewModel)x);
```

Comment: Yes, so no option to do it without iterating.

Comment: Correct, each object must be individually cast. If iterating presents a performance issue, you could take a lazy approach to the cast and defer it to when each viewmodel is used rather than all at once. Look into [Enumerable.Cast<TResult>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **LINQ**-Functions

```
.Cast<SponsoredBrandViewModel>()
```

or

```
.OfType<SponsoredBrandViewModel>()
```

to achieve that. These will iterate over the result too, but in a lazy way. Use the first one if you are sure every element is of this type, the later one if you want to filter only the matching elements.